# Is it possible to do transition between 2 views belong to different UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I used navigationController to push and pop 2 viewcontrollers.
But I hope to do transition (just like CATransition fade) with 5 seconds interval between the views of the 2 viewcontrollers.
Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: I think it is possible. And I am curious about answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CATransition` like so:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 5.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition 
                                            forKey:kCATransition];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.alternateView
                                     animated:NO];
```